# Text blocked by error bars on Plotly bar graph

Tags: python, graph, format, plotly, bar-chart

I'm trying to have a bar plot with error bars and data labels but I cant find how to change the location of the text so that the error bars don't interfere with the labels. [This is an example of what I currently have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zCgyu.png), and here's the code for that:

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
y = [100, 90, 80, 70, 60, 50]
y_err = [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

fig = go.Figure(data=go.Bar(x=x, y=y, error_y_array=y_err, text=y, textposition="inside"))
fig.show()
```

I want the label to be at the bottom of the bar ideally, but any other way of ensuring that the data isn't covered works too. I need the data to be within the bar and oriented horizontally. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would simply just annotate each bar, the only valid args for `textposition` are `['inside', 'outside', and 'auto']. So in that case loop through the lists and add the text like so:

```py
import plotly.graph_objects as go

x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
y = [100, 90, 80, 70, 60, 50]
y_err = [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

fig = go.Figure(data=go.Bar(x=x, y=y, error_y_array=y_err))

i=0
text_height = 5
for x_val in x:
    fig.add_annotation(
        x=x_val,
        y=text_height, 
        text=str(y[i]),
        showarrow=False,
        font=(dict(color='white'))
    )
    i = i+1
```

Output:
[image: Bar chart, text bottom, plotly]

Answer (score 0):

This is a hacky solution, but if the text labels are short enough you can also just add whitespace to them to force them to the right or left of the error bars. Good solution for people trying to stick with plotly express.

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
y = [100, 90, 80, 70, 60, 50]
y_labels = ['             {}'.format(y_val) for y_val in y]
y_err = [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

fig = go.Figure(data=go.Bar(x=x, y=y, error_y_array=y_err, text=y_labels, textposition="outside"))
fig.show()
```